# jQuery mobile: change text header/footer remove fixed property

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

Here's the working stuff: [working sample](http://www.doonoo.com/t/hh.php)
Try to scroll: it works, the header and footer are fixed.

Now, click on any cell of the table and scroll: the header and footer are not fixed anymore whereas I'm just changing the text in it:

```
$('.header h1').html(txt);
$('.footer h4').html(txt);
```

I'm generating a table and when the user clicks on a cell, header and footer are modified. Here's my script here:

```
var cellClick = function() {
    var txt=
        '"'+$(this).html()+'" = '+
        $(this).attr('data-unicode');
    $('.header h1').html(txt);
    $('.footer h4').html(txt);
};
```

After googling a lot - and watching results here, I haven't found a "working workaround".

Comment: Just add `data-tap-toggle="false"` to both footer and header.

Comment: You're right, may I ask you to answer to I can check it as valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Mobile's toolbars get hidden once tapped on screen. To prevent then from hiding on `tap`, add `data-tap-toggle="false"` attribute to both divs.

```
<div data-role="header" data-tap-toggle="false">
</div>

<div data-role="footer" data-tap-toggle="false">
</div>
```